# Proper name for different type of headers

Tags: connector, header

Here are the three types:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please click on the image to enlarge it. The image gets too big or too small. I am not able to keep it in reasonable size.

All of these contain pins of 0.1" pitch. They are all called headers but they are not the same. I am just trying to understand, what is the proper terminology to differentiate between these.

Comment: As far as I know there aren’t formal standards for terminology.  Apart from using individual manufacturers’ designations though, the conventions appeared to be ‘pin header’ for a fully exposed header and ‘box header’ for a fully enclosed one.  I suppose the middle one is a partially shrouded connector.

Comment: partially shrouded, hmmm

Comment: The middle, blue one looks a lot like the PCB mounting half of a ribbon cable-to-PCB pair of connectors. The mating female half is often IDC (Insulation Displacement Connector) and are widely used. I can't see it in the image, but there is usually a key on the side of the female half and a corresponding notch on the male part to ensure correct orientation.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom two are headers with a shroud, the middle one is a 2-wall the bottom one is a lock. The first one is a 0.1" header, could be breakaway. There are hundreds of thousands of headers.

Check digikey [rectangular connectors](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/headers-male-pins/314) for additional search terms.

Comment: I thought shroud was supposed to cover all 4 sides rather than just 2 sides? Also, some "shrouded" connectors have no cuts at all, but some have a small cut on one of the long sides like shown in the image.

Comment: Apparently not, thats how the market terms list them

Comment: Could also say "boxed header"

Answer (score 2):

1. Unshrouded male PCB header - aka [pin strip](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=unshrouded_male_headers_2p54) (Disclosure: This is my website.)
2. Prismatic male PCB header - [2-wall](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=prismatic_conn&&fl=0000000000000000000060000000000000000000220000000000-410-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) (Disclosure: This is my website.)
3. Prismatic male PCB header - [bump IDC](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=prismatic_bump_idc_conn)  (Disclosure: This is my website.)